# How to create irregular raster with gdal using csv points

Tags: raster, gdal, shapefile, geotiff

I am trying to create a irregular shaped .tiff from a csv list of points (xyz data). I am doing this using gdal_grid.

I can seem to generate the .tiff file no problem but I cannot preserve the outline / shape of the original csv points.

Everytime I generate the .tiff file it creates a raster with the size of (xmax-xmin) x (ymax-ymin) and assigns interpolated values to pixels that fall far away from my initial points.

Is it possible to generate a .tiff file of ONLY the points I provide?

For context, I am trying to generate a raster of xyz data for a river, and only want the raster in the river (not the entire bounding box of the river). I am only providing xyz data in the river.

I tried playing with the -nodata flag, and limiting -max_points to the number of points I've provided.

My final code (once everything is imported and declared):

gdal_grid -a invdist:power=2.0:smoothing=1.0:nodata=-999:max_points=2128164 -txe 582387.4 591069.4 -tye 4505028.08 4515344.079999999 -outsize 50 50 -zfield "z" -of GTiff -ot Float64 -l Book2 Book2.vrt Book2.tiff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, Derek!

Maybe there is a creation option inside gdal_grid that would do it, but I think that you will have to achieve desired result with additional calculation:

1. Run the gdal_grid as you have it.
2. Create a [concave hull](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/addons/v.concave.hull.html) from the given points. If this is a one time job, I suggest using QGIS (with grass tools), because there is some tweaking of concave hull parameters required.
3. Cut the raster with the created shapefile by using [gdalwarp](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45053/gdalwarp-cutline-along-with-shapefile).

Let me know if this got you through!

Comment: Thanks for the information :D 

I basically ended up doing exactly what you suggested, however my shape is quite irregular so both concave/convex hull methods were giving me strange "boundaries" of the points. 

As a temporary work-around I just made my own shapefile tracing around the outer points and used it to cut the raster with it.

Going to look into a better way to generate a boundary of a complex shape...any suggestions? (I am very new to this so please dont go too deep :D)